# Getting Facebook user IP address

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, ip

In my project, users login to my application through a Facebook Login button. I get all details of user but if user doesn't have location, I need to find his location based on their IP address. Is there any way of finding the location of user based on their IP address using the Facebook API?

Answer (score 1):

Using PHP, you can get the user's IP using `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']`.
I don't know if getting the IP is possible through Javascript, but you can make an AJAX call to your server and have your server process it that way.

You can compare the IP against a Geolocation Database, here is a [list of databases](http://whatismyipaddress.com/geolocation-providers).

Please note:
IPv6 was enabled earlier in the week, so there will be possibly two sets of IP addresses to consider.